# jQuery Mobile ListView equivalent for jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

We've been using the JQuery Listview (listviewbeforefilter) functionality for a JQuery Mobile application.

Specifically functionality similar to this:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/listviews/listview-filter-autocomplete.html

Does anybody know of an equivalent widget in the normal JQuery UI world or do I need to roll my own?

We've spent time developing a JQuery mobile app and it needs to be re-used and expanded into a desktop web-browser type application. I don't think that JQuery Mobile is suitable for the desktop browser version. There isn't really time to learn new frameworks unfortunately.

Comment: There's no reason why you can't use the jQuery Mobile functionality in a desktop deployment.  You can then skin it differently by changing CSS.  Also considering a lot of viewing of sites is migrating to tablets and phones, your users will probably be quite happy with the styling of JQM.

Comment: But can you do jquery mobile multi-column stuff? The stuff i've read looks like jquery mobile multiview is a hack which involves rewriting parts of the core-library to make it work...

Comment: Not sure about multi-column stuff.  Pehaps https://datatables.net/ can give you what you want?  They have a search function in the table.

Comment: Maybe the content-grids will help me achieve what i need to do in jquery mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/content/content-grids.html